# Opening msg files, produced by parallels-plesk-backup system - howto?

Tags: email, backup

I can't open these files, any advice?

---

edit:

The original hosting service was with mochahost. It was a windows plan.
The control panel was plesk 9.
I used the CP backup tool to backup the complete account with all the domains.

The backup process produced a single file, compressed.
In the file there are more compressed files, one of the is the mail (its name is: complete_backup_mydomainname_domainmail_1106131304.zip), where `mydomainname` was my real domain..

After extracting this file and sub-files, i can access almost any file (html's, php's and others) not the emails.

The files have the msg extension.

I hope that now my question is clearer.
any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Open them with an text editor of your choice and your Operating System.

Comment: been there, done that. also used hex editor and about 30 different apps. no luck. i will edit the original question and supply more info. i will also attach a file

Comment: @yossi So with "no luck" you mean "access denied"?